# Top answers duplicated on community wiki question

Tags: support, answers

The two most-upvoted answers on this question are identical: [Should curly braces appear on their own line?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line) It seems like a bug... surely the exact same answer would not have been upvoted so much *twice*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the answers they are not identical:

> I find the **first** method more readable, especially if you have nested blocks.
>
> The **second** method reminds me of basic, it's like you're trying to **not** forget that the braces are there.

and:

> I find the **second** method more readable, especially if you have nested blocks.
>
> The **first** method reminds me of basic, it's like you're trying to forget that the braces are there.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Uh, wow. Totally missed that.

Comment: you forgot to mention that both answers are low quality crap. "Polling items" as far from SE Q&A model as it gets, not even attempting to provide an explanation and context. Without an explanation, both answers are demonstrably useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. In a presence of a different claim, none of these answers help reader to pick of two opposing opinions. Side note high score of the post that just shows funny picture reminds me of [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: @gnat - Indeed, but as the question is closed I didn't think it necessary to do anything with those answers. However, removing them will probably make the usefulness of the question go up so...

Comment: @ChrisF yeah I somehow also hesitate to suggest plain removal, especially since these are dated 2010. Historical lock... maybe. Hard to tell, I need more time to think it through

Comment: @gnat - well they've gone now. The more useful "be consistent" answers which have either been accepted or bountied are what we should be promoting.

Comment: @ChrisF thanks! it looks much better now (question still feels not quite okay by current standards, but many of the answers make it worth keeping)

Answer (score 2):

You should look better, they are not the same and they are an attempt at humor.

Clearly pointless here because [we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).